# возвращение значений с помощью curl

Tags: php, массивы, curl

такой вопрос, я с помощью curl отправляю некий массив

```
$search_file = array();
foreach ($_POST['check'] as $key) {
$current = $_POST['search_text'] . "." . $key;
array_push($search_file, $current);
}
$data = array('search_file' => $search_file);
$string = http_build_query($data);
$url = "адрес_серваера";
$quer = curl_init();
curl_setopt($quer, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($quer, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($quer, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($quer, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

на втором сайта я его обрабатываю, делаю с ним все необходимые махинации и на выходе он уже получается даже массив внутри которого ассоциативный массив

```
$output = curl_exec($quer);

if ($output === false)
echo "url" . curl_error($quer);
else {
echo $output;
echo gettype($output);
}

curl_close($quer);
```

но моя переменная $output на выходе постоянно получается string, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как вы выводите данные?

Второй сайт формирует массив, например `$ARRAY`.

Выводим его через `json_encode($ARRAY);` - там будет строковое представление вашего массива, потом вы эту строчку принимаете на первом сайте: `$output = curl_exec($quer);` и сразу после нее преобразуете строку обратно в массив `$output = json_decode($output);`